# sprintf always write format into string, wrong on 64bit linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am using the func of sprintf on 64bit linux. Weird thing happens when I tested the string written by sprintf or snprintf. The way I used it:

```
char s[256];
int current=0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    current += sprintf(s+current, "d", i);
}

printf("string is %s \n", s);
```

All I get is : string is ddddd, if I change sprintf(s,"d", i) to "c" or "lf", all I get is ccccc or lflflflflf.   Anyone has any clue about this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use %d for integers, d itself is not special

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to use %d instead of d

See [man 3 printf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/)

Answer (score 2):

you should louk up `man printf` on command line. It will tell you, your format string should be "%d"